# Is there some built-in method in the form "await RunManyTimesConcurrently(numberOfTimes, myAction)"?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

### TL/DR:

I wonder if there's a "c# built-in elegant way" running a `Task`/`Action` multiples times in parallel, something like:

```
await RunManyTimesConcurrently(numberOfTimes, myAction);
```

Is there ?

---

### Explanation:

I have certain `Action` or `Action<T1,T2,...>` or even a `Task` or `Task` or `Task<T1,T2,...>`. I want to launch that action/task `N` times, and `await` for all of them to finish. I can do this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    tasks.Add(new Task(() => myAction));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or:

```
var parallelForAction = new Action(() => Parallel.For(0, N, myAction));
await Task.Run(parallelForAction);
```

I don't like the 1st method: it creates a `List<Task>` needlessly. I don't like the 2nd way either: it creates kind of redundant "envelope" `Task`...

I wonder if there's a "c# built-in elegant way" of doing it, something like:

```
await RunManyTimesConcurrently(N, myAction);
```

Comment: You can *hide* some of the mechanics of your first option with something like `await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(()=>Task.Run(myAction));`. Behind the scenes, ~the same amount of work is taking place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It's still makes you add unnecessary stuff (`IEnumerable<int>` to use with the `.Select(...)`), so it's not much different...

Comment: Yes, but you're now at the point where you can write `RunManyTimesConcurrently` as a one-liner yourself. And it's not (in my experience) a common need to run the same action multiple times without some form of parameterization. I'd think that those are two reasons why you're unlikely to find a built-in method to do this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you convinced me... that's what I finally did... since you have no answer, and [Adriano](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139659/587467) already gave that answer, I accepted his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example will be:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, _ => myAction());
```

`Parallel.For()` will end when all tasks will be performed (because here they can't break execution) so there is no need to call `WhenAll()` or `await`. It's trivial to change that code to invoke delegates from an array or to pass them one or more parameters. Just for example:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => myAction(i, somethingElse));
```

Please note that `somethingElse` will be accessed concurrently so it must be thread-safe (at least for reading). If it's not you have to handle synchronization inside `myAction` (whatever it is: method or delegate).

If you need to await this you can wrap that for inside a Task (as you said) or to create multiple tasks (to wait with `WhenAll()`). In this second case:

```
var tasks Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => Task.Run(() => doSomething(i));
```

Or (if you're working with an `Action` delegate without parameters):

```
var tasks Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(_ => Task.Run(doSomething);
```

For parallel execution of `Task` you even have less code to write because you can use them directly as parameters for `WhenAll()`. If you have one single `Task` and you want to run it multiple times in parallel...you're unlucky because you can't get back task's action so you can run it multiple times only synchronously.

Comment: But the whole point is to return a `Task`, to run it as an `async`, I want to be able to `await` for the `Paraller.For(...)`